# D3: zoom to bounding box with d3-tiles

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have successfully layered a D3 (vector) map on top of a d3-tile (raster) map that pulls tiles from Mapbox. The manual zoom works perfectly, and both vector and raster are in sync.

I am now trying to implement the Mike Bostock '[zoom-to-bounding-box](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4699541)' feature, whereby the application zooms on a desired country upon user click. I think I am nearly there, but right now there seems to be a mismatch and the map zooms out into outer space, so to speak.

**I have reproduced the issue in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/m7cn0p47/1/).**

What do I need to amend in the 'zoomed' function so that the map zooms correctly and as expected? I think this is where the issue lies:

```
  vector.selectAll("path")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + [transform.x, transform.y] + ")scale(" + transform.k + ")")
    .style("stroke-width", 1 / transform.k);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: It looks like the main issue is just the update of projection

### Using a constant projection

The main issue here is that you're changing the projection based on zooming and calculating the bounding box from them.

In zoomed, you have this line:

```
projection.scale...
```

It seems like you're trying to update the projection based on your zooming, but translating and scaling are already handled by the `transform` attribute of the svg elements.

The projection is instead used to translate spherical geographic coordinates into 2d space. It's used to calculate the bounds of a country and if it changes, the bounds move around, which is probably unintended. Removing this projection update gets you most of the way there.

The other big issue is that you clamp the scale in your click handler to values that are a lot lower than what you need (for instance you clamp the scale to a max of 8, but have an initial scale of 4096).

Removing the clamp and the projection update should get you click-to-zoom on countries. But we're not done yet!

Another issue is that your `reset` function does not reset to the original view, which makes it zoom off into the distance. Using the initial zoom settings instead of `d3.zoomIdentity` addresses the problem.

The results of these edits are here: https://jsfiddle.net/m7cn0p47/99/

### Optional: Consolidating Transforms

It's generally inefficient to alter many DOM nodes. In this case you're altering each of your path vectors in `zoomed`. Applying the transform to one `g` element (in this case the `g` element with id `vector`) instead is usually more efficient.

Instead of:

```
vector.selectAll("path")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + [transform.x, transform.y] + ")scale(" + transform.k + ")")
  .style("stroke-width", 1 / transform.k);
```

You can change it to simply:

```
vector
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + [transform.x, transform.y] + ")scale(" + transform.k + ")")
  .style("stroke-width", 1 / transform.k);
```

You'll also have to remove `stroke-width` from path in the CSS because it is overwriting it.

Here's an updated fiddle with those changes and corrections: https://jsfiddle.net/m7cn0p47/96/

Comment: Steve, this is a very thorough and comprehensive answer. I am very grateful for taking the time to share this. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words-- glad that it worked out!

Comment: Hello Alex - just a quick question. I have been tinkering with your code using the following tileset: `.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.natural-earth-2/`. How might I adjust your zoom to bounding box script such that the viewport does not display 'unavailable' tiles at higher zoom levels? The idea is that the zoom should bet set at a maximum k where tiles can exist and therefore be displayed...?

Comment: Lex, I have created a new question regarding the above. You can find it here - your insights would be much appreciated! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50834044/limit-zoom-to-a-maximum-in-d3-geo-tiles

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if you intended this for Lex, but his answer is the other one. I did answer your updated question, though I won't be on Stack Overflow for a few weeks.

Answer (score 2):

In your example you're applying a transformation directly to the parent SVG. In the bl.ocks example they created a group `g` inside the svg to apply the transformation to.

In your zoom function you're using css transformations as does the bl.ocks click zoom example. Updating to css transformation functions in the `clickHandler` and the same scale calculations as in the example, the click scaling works correctly.

https://jsfiddle.net/bamboo/m7cn0p47/3/

The scaling works better on states or more atomic sections. Places like USA, France Spain all have remote islands or Alaska. Which can give the effect of zooming *out* when its actually just including the surrounding areas.

Comment: Hello Lex, thank you for providing what looks like a very promising answer. Are you sure you have referenced the right fiddle? The one you have referenced has the United States layered over Africa and does not seem to be scaling as expected. Please let me know if I am missing something, and thanks again.

Comment: Lex, this is again very promising, and I am going through your script to understand what you have done. There is an issue, however, in that when you are zooming in to country you are not refreshing the tiles as you zoom in. Your script just 'freezes' the raster layer, so to speak, and does not present the more detailed tiles as you get closer, and vice versa when you zoom out. Is this a small issue? I am not sure. Please check the following to see what I mean about refreshing the tiles: http://plnkr.co/edit/8muX27u0kSnuPwtmmZlU?p=preview

Comment: Any ideas? Have been tinkering with your code but cannot get this to work... :)