# Limit zoom to a 'maximum' in d3 geo tiles

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When you use certain tile-sets (e.g. `.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.natural-earth-2/`) the zoom on d3 geo tiles should be limited to a maximum, otherwise those tiles do not exist, cannot be found, and end up displaying an ugly 'cannot be found' background image.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/5Lf0w3sm/1/) (courtesy of user [Lex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615397/lex)) to show you exactly what I mean. Try clicking on a small country to replicate the issue. No tiles exist at that zoom level. The following two solutions would be acceptable.

1. How would I set about limiting the zoom in function `clicked` that
   calculates the zoom-to-bounding-box?
2. How would I amend the script such that function `clicked` continues to zoom into the most detailed tile available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy approach to this is to limit the zoom by setting a maximum scaling factor.

For instance in `clicked` you could add a line like this:

```
scale = Math.min(1 << 14, scale);
```

(based your previous scale extent of `[1 << 11, 1 << 14]`)

Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5Lf0w3sm/17/

Comment: Thank you Steve. I am not sure I understand  [1 << 11, 1 <<14] and what that does, but your fiddle certainly solved my issue.